# Rank all possible groupby combinations

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Let's say I have the below table of sample data:

```
Country Group   Revenue
US      A           $50 
US      B          $125 
MX      A          $100 
CA      A           $70 
CA      C           $10
```

What I want to do is calculate revenue across every possible combination of Country and Group like this:

```
US  $175 
MX  $100 
CA  $80 
A   $220 
B   $125 
C   $10 
US, A   $50 
US, B   $125 
MX, A   $100 
CA, A   $70 
CA, C   $10
```

And then be able to sort to see which combinations provide the most revenue:

```
A       $220 
US      $175 
B       $125 
US, B   $125 
MX      $100 
MX, A   $100 
CA      $80 
CA, A   $70 
US, A   $50 
C       $10 
CA, C   $10
```

Ideally I'd like to do this in Pandas, but open to other ideas. Also bonus points for anyone who can tell me the proper name for this type of analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> pd.concat([df,
...            df.groupby('Country', as_index=False).sum(),
...            df.groupby('Group', as_index=False).sum()],
...           ignore_index=True).sort(columns='Revenue',
...                                   ascending=False).fillna('')
   Country Group  Revenue
8              A      220
7       US            175
1       US     B      125
9              B      125
2       MX     A      100
6       MX            100
5       CA             80
3       CA     A       70
0       US     A       50
4       CA     C       10
10             C       10
```